# Solid model to networked model

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender. I am currently working with a bone and I have a solid model of it. Now I want to convert it into either a dense networked structure or a solid porous structure. Is there any tool to help me with this in this software or can anyone suggest me any other software if its not possible in this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: check out the built in Tissue Add-on https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Mesh/Tissue/

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and update the results !!